# Mysql Query optimization and update needed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my Codeigniter Query

```
 $this->db->select('o.*,seo.price as seo_price,SUM(domain.price) as domain_price,SUM(bes.price) as bes_price, SUM(op.price) as payment_price');
    $this->db->from('order as o');
    $this->db->join("order_package_seo as seo", "seo.order_id = o.id", "left");
    $this->db->join("order_package_domain as domain", "domain.order_id = o.id", "left");
    $this->db->join("order_package_bespoke as bes", "bes.order_id = o.id", "left");
    $this->db->join("order_payment as op", "op.order_id = o.id", "left"); 
    $this->db->where("o.id" , $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
```

I have 3 records in "order_package_beskope" table and 1 in others all 
I want to get price from all table by **Order_id** 
is i need to use group_by distinct or any other method need you suggestion.

Comment: ok so what's it returning..

Comment: it's returning all prices multiple by 3 . i.e domain price is 123 but its returning 369.

Comment: i can explain more if you can help ..

Comment: Hi @IrfanAli, there is no word in English like: Updation. I have corrected it. Check this: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68172/33415

Comment: Have you already tried to add `$this->db->group_by("o.id");` after `$this->db->where("o.id" , $id);`?

Comment: yes i tried but no change

Answer (score 0):

Change the first statement like this

```
$this->db->select('o.*,seo.price as seo_price,domain.price ,SUM(bes.price) as bes_price, op.price as payment_price');
$this->db->from('order as o');
$this->db->join("order_package_seo as seo", "seo.order_id = o.id", "left");
$this->db->join("order_package_domain as domain", "domain.order_id = o.id", "left");
$this->db->join("order_package_bespoke as bes", "bes.order_id = o.id", "left");
$this->db->join("order_payment as op", "op.order_id = o.id", "left"); 
$this->db->where("o.id" , $id);
$this->db->group_by("o.id");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

Because, you mentioned the table "order_package_beskope" has 3 records, so only that table field "bes_price" needs the SUM. All the other tables has only one record so if you add SUM, it will get multiplied by 3(number of order_package_bespoke records).

So remove the SUM from other tables fields in SELECT and add group by o.id